# GDAL for Java on Windows, native library error

Tags: java, swig, gdal

I know it's probably fairly simple, but I'm having some issues grasping all the different packages I need just to install GDAL and read georeferenced rasters.

So I have already had OSGEO4W installed so that there exists a folderpath as follows: `C:\OsGeo4W\lib\gdal.jar` as well as `C:\OsGeo4W\apps\swigwin\swig.exe`

I also have the version from http://vbkto.dyndns.org/sdk/ so that I have a folderpath as follows: `C:\ProjectsJava\gdal\bin\gdal\java\` with a gdal.jar and a bunch of dll's. This is what is originally linked in my project's libraries.

After googling the problem, I've also added a `-Djava.library.path` to point to the above gdal folderpath in the project's VM options (not entirely sure what I did but didn't make a difference anyways).

Also from random googled answers I've added environment variables to windows point to this and that related to GDAL or SWIG that did nothing (so removed them for now). So I only have a `PATH` that points to the gdal/bin folder and a `GDAL_DATA` that points to the gdal/bin/gdal-data folder. If it makes any difference I have installed successfully GDAL bindings for Python and there are some of it's environment variables left over in PATH and GDAL_DATA as well to similar but different folders.

Basically the code fails to even run a `gdal.Open(in_path)`, giving the following error which hasn't changed no matter what I did differently:

```
Native library load failed.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\ProjectsJava\gdal\bin\gdal\jave\gdaljni.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.gdal.gdal.gdalJNI.Open__SWIG_1(Ljava/lang/String;)J'
  at org.gdal.gdal.gdalJNI.Open__SWIG_1(Native Method)
  at org.gdal.gdal.gdal.Open(gdal.java:563)
  at ...
```

Now I know I probably screwed up getting GDAL right, but to be honest the labyrinthical instructions lost me well early on. All the odd packages to adapt C++ code to Java and instructions meant for Unix/Linux have got me all mixed up now.

**SOLVED**

Not sure why, but reinstalling Microsoft 2010 C++ Redistributable Package x86 helped. It was already installed, did a fix installation, and that seemed to do the trick. Hope that helps anyone else with a similar issue.